# Who/What is the "suspicious character" in the Leaky Cauldron?

Tags: harry-potter

After Harry blows up his aunt in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, he stays in the Leaky Cauldron. After the first night JKR describes what he sees in Diagon Alley.

There she mentions a 'suspicious character' who orders raw liver.
I don't have an English quote because I only have the German audio book but it was in the 4th chapter "In the Leaky Cauldron".

I think it is a werewolf maybe even Fenrir... But I don't know if there are any outside sources...

Comment: I highly doubt there is any official word on who it actually is.  My english (American) version says "... and once, what looked suspiciously like a hag, who ordered a plate of raw liver from behind a thick woollen balaclava".  It just seems like a one-off character to me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is supposed to be a random customer of the Leaky Cauldron, who Harry thinks might be a hag.

> and once, what looked suspiciously like a hag, who ordered a plate of raw liver from behind a thick woolen balaclava.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be Sirius Black? Since the person was hiding their face and Sirius couldn't show his face in the magical world.

I was rereading HP and felt that Sirius may be lurking around Harry in The Leaky Cauldron and Diagon Alley. It says that Harry would always go and look at the Fire Bolt room in the window of the shop, and in *Prisoner of Azkaban* Sirius gifts Harry a Fire Bolt.

Comment: Note that your original answer was deleted by users and as such it is usually advisable to not repost the exact same answer. I.e. it might be worth you [edit]ing this to add a bit more reasoning/evidence for this potentially being Sirius. That said I don'y believe your answer should have been deleted in the first place.

Comment: I simply asked if anyone felt like that. I didnt mean to impose this assumption on others. This was my first comment in this website. I seriously felt very bad and it seemed to me that opinions cant be said in this website. I will continue reading and try to see if any more evidences r there.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a question and answer site so answers should be answers (which this is) and so this is not a comment. Asking for opinions or if others agree is a continuation of the discussion and more of a discussion forum thing which this is not. You might also want to take the [tour] to get an idea of how the site works.

Comment: Ok then it was my mistake. I thought of this as a discussion forum. Thanks for informing 

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer in the state it is now. Please don't vandalise it.

Comment: Not a bad point, I suppose I never thought to ask how Sirius knew Harry wanted a Firebolt. Just assumed he got Harry the best replacement broom he could find.